# Geting error 10013 while creating a socket on loopback IP 127.0.0.1, and general error while pinging 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows, sockets, ping

I recently started having an annoying symptom.

On my system running Windows 10, I can not use the loopback IP 127.0.0.1 to establish a socket, I get a 10013 error code. If I use the IP address assigned by DHCP to the same system, the socket can be established fine.

Further testing shows I can not ping 127.0.0.1, either.  It will report a "general failure", as below:

```
Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
```

The system is a Hyper-V VM running 32bit Windows 10 Enterprise (version 1607 build 14393.693) as a guest OS.

I have disabled Windows Defender, updated the Hyper-V network driver, but nothing helps.

I also tested some suggestions I found on the Internet, such as `/flushdns`,  `netsh int ipv4 reset`, etc, but I still can not resolve the issue.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve) showing your actual socket code.  As for the ping errors, on my Windows 7 system, `ping` always fails if I am not running the Command Prompt window with elevated permissions, I do not know why. Are you pinging with elevated rights?

Comment: Have you considered looking up Winsock error code 10013?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try deactivation IPV6? (just for a short test if it works then)

Did you correctly set the Gateway in the LAN Settings inside the VM?

Have you bridged the LAN Interface from your host?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. I turned off the Firewall, and chose "Use Windows Recommended Settings", then the Firewall is turned on again. Now the loopback IP 127.0.0.1 can be pinged. In addition, after the issue is resolved, I turned the firewall off, the loopback IP is still ping'able.

I think there are some security setting is refreshed by turning on the Firewall with recommended setting, because I ever directly turned on the Firewall by clicking the "On" button, but couldn't fix.